# Searched text in search input after submit (PHP)

Tags: php

On my site people search for something according on VIN they enter to form. I try to add VIN to session to be able to display it in form after they submit it.

This is how my contructor looks like:

```
 public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
     if( isset( $data['vin'] ) )  $this->vin = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['vin']) );
     $this->vin = str_replace("I","1",str_replace("O","0",$this->vin)); // replace i  for 1 and o for 0
     $_SESSION['vin'] =  $this->vin;
 }
```

My HTML site looks like:

```
<input type="text"  maxlength="17" minlength="17" required autofocus name="vin" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['vin'])) {echo $_SESSION['vin'];} ?>">
```

And now the problem:
It display there old vin. 
Example:
1. I search for vin XYZ 
2. I pres submit and get result for vin XYZ but input bar is empty
3. I search for vin ABC and now after i submit it i get result for ABC but in input i have XYZ vin from session

My idea was that my php site do not reload or something but it should if i get result from submit..

Any idea how can i display current VIN in search input?

Comment: You need to execute the PHP code which sets the $_SESSION before you run the display code which reads from $_SESSION.

Comment: Oh, its going to be problem in my case, but thanks mate you help me to understand it